# How do I get a local encrypted file as a FileStream?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, .net-8.0

I have **files stored locally** and **encrypted** with **aes**.

I need one of the documents in the code in decrypted form as a Stream.
I try back and forth and can't get it to work.

**What must the method look like so that I get the Stream back with decrypted content.**

```
public Stream DecryptFile(string filePath){..??..}
```

My method for encrypting is as follows:

```
public async Task EncryptAndSaveFileAsync(Stream stream, string filePath)
{
    await using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    try
    {
        if (!stream.CanRead)
        {
            stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        }

        await using (var tempFileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(tempFileStream);
        }

        fileStream.Close();

        try
        {
            await using var inputFileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            await using (var outputFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using var aesAlg = Aes.Create();
                aesAlg.Key = _key;
                aesAlg.IV = new byte[16];

                await using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputFileStream, aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                await inputFileStream.CopyToAsync(cryptoStream);
            }

            inputFileStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fehler beim Verschlüsseln der Datei: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO FM Logging
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(tempFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: `await using var inputFileStream` why is there the `await` keyword there?

Comment: @gunr2171 To release all resources from stream. (Is a suggestion from Resharper)

Comment: Why must it be a FileStream? A stream should make sense.

Comment: @shingo Yes, a Stream would be fine. I adjust the article.

Comment: `aesAlg.IV = new byte[16]` is almost certainly a bug. The IV should (secure) random and unique per encryption, see [GenerateIV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.generateiv?view=net-8.0).  As for how to encrypt/decrypt, see [Encrypting Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data) / [Decrypting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/decrypting-data)

Answer (score 2):

Your encryption code is wrong for a start:

- There is no need for messing about with temp files. You can write directly to `cryptoStream`.
- Do not blank out the `IV`, it's securely generated and needs to be there to keep the algorithm secure.
- The IV should be pre- or appended to the encrypted result.
- There is no point passing the key and IV to `CreateEncryptor`, that is the default.

```cs
public async Task EncryptAndSaveFileAsync(Stream stream, string filePath)
{
    await using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    using var aesAlg = Aes.Create();
    aesAlg.Key = _key;
    await fileStream.WriteAsync(aesAlg.IV.AsMemory());

    await using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    await stream.CopyToAsync(cryptoStream);
}
```

Then the decryption is the same thing in reverse.

```cs
public async Task<Stream> DecryptFile(string filePath)
{
    await using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

    using var aesAlg = Aes.Create();
    aesAlg.Key = _key;
    var iv = new byte[16];
    await fileStream.ReadExactlyAsync(iv.AsMemory());
    aesAlg.IV = iv;

    await using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    var mem = new MemoryStream();
    await cryptoStream.CopyToAsync(mem);
    return mem;
}
```

Comment: In EncryptAndSaveFileAsync is used inputFileStream which not exists. When I use fileStream instead I get a exception "Stream does not support reading".
At DecryptFile is uses _iv which is not known. Do you mean iv? I used iv and it does not work for me.

Comment: OK fixed all that. The decryption expects you to store the IV at the beginning of the file. If you haven't done that then you need to modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method:

```
public Stream? DecryptFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        using var inputFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        using var aesAlg = Aes.Create();

        aesAlg.Key = _key;
        aesAlg.IV = _iv;

        using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputFileStream, aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        var decryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
        cryptoStream.CopyTo(decryptedStream);
        decryptedStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return decryptedStream;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO Logging
        return null;
    }
}
```